# How to find which pid is modify the file

Tags: pid

I want to modify a sas file. But the liunx system told me that it is readonly and it had been used by other program. So, I want to find which PID is using this file and try to kill the PID. How could I find this PID, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some commands to verify the process in execution to kill. A tool that I like to use is the `pgrep`, where i search for the name of the application and it returns me the pid.

Ex:

```
pgrep firefox
```

Output:

```
2588
```

Or, you can use other commons tools:
`top`, `ps`.

Comment: The file is a sas code file, it can be called by sas or called by bash. It is a little bit hard to find which pid is calling it. That is why I want to directly find the pid and kill it.

Comment: Using the var $SYSJOBID works? i see [here](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Get_Process_ID_(PID)_of_SAS_Tasks_Running_on_Unix_and_Linux). Sorry if this is not the answer, a i never used sas file.